# Adding <small> tag inside Wordpress Date Formatting function

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Still learning my way around WordPress and its template functions, but basically I am just trying to quickly put a post date format into my design like they are in my HTML mark up below:

```
<span class="date">29 <small>JUN 2014</small></span>

.date {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #313131;
}

.date small {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Which is displaying as desired on the pages:

[image: Wordpress Date]

**EDIT**:

Using the links provided and suggestion by Bradley in his answer below. I now have the correct date format with this code:

```
<?php $my_date = the_date('j M Y', '<span class="date">', '</span>'); echo $my_date; ?>
```

How do I add the `<small>` tag in front of the `M` in the date?

Many Thanks

Comment: so whats the question? are you trying to figure out the css classes you need to style that wordpress renders inside a post?

Comment: How do I call the post date function:
<?php the_date('Y-m-d', '<span class="date">', '</span>'); ?>

So that the date format is how I want (29 Jun 2014) and apply it to that markup - css and html has already been done as shown in the code.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for explaining, here is the [wordpress codex on the_date function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date) And here is a link on [formatting](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time)

I am unsure if the small tag is going to work in the date format section, if not, you will save it into a variable(see the codex), replace the small tag with a comma and use a php or js replace to switch the comma with the small tag, then echo it out in the place you want to render it.

So in your case it would be `the_date('d <small>D Y', '<span class='date'>', '</small></span>');`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bradley. After playing around with your code I am close at:

 <?php 
                                        $my_date = the_date('j M Y', '<span class="date">', '</span>'); 
                                        echo $my_date;
                                    ?>

I am having some difficult adding the <small> into the date format string even using a variable. Are you able to give a solution for that? Cheers

Comment: sure, so where you have j M Y, I would add a comma between the j and M so j, M Y. That way you can do a string replace using php, so it would be like $my_date_formatted = str_replace(",", "<small> ", $my_date); also you will want to add in the ending small tag at the end of the string like I have it in my above example, that way you dont have to worry about closing it, then you can echo $my_date_formatted and it should print what you want.

Comment: @sintax did this help at all??

Comment: Thanks for your answer again. I added the following: <?php 
                                        $my_date = the_date('j ,M Y', '<span class="date">', '</small></span>'); 
                                        $my_date_formatted = str_replace(" ,", "<small>", $my_date);
                                        echo $my_date_formatted;
                                    ?>Unfortunately not Bradley! :( just get it printing the comma out in the date

Comment: Hmm, do you have a link or some code i could take a look at? is it printing the tags around the comma, so the span and the small tag, or just a comma with no tags around it?

Comment: That is the code pasted, it's running locally.. It is printing just the comma with no tags around it but does not have the closing </small> tag either before the <span> tag closes out and it is as typed.. Thanks for your help on this :)

Answer (score 0):

for me, works this:

```
'\<\s\p\a\n\>j M Y\<\/\s\p\a\n\>'
or
'j <\s\p\a\n\>M</\s\p\a\n\> Y'
```

with this, you can put any code you wanted... :)

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.